# Meaning of the lock and strange symbol in GitHub Desktop client

Tags: git, symbolic-link, gui, github

What does that two symbols mean in GitHub Desktop client?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

If someone knows the name for the second symbol, write it here please.

I mean symbols on the left of the projects name: lock and that other strange symbol. And I am interested in their meanings as well.

Comment: Guessing here: Lock means private repo, second symbol means forked repo (a repository that has been forked off of another - see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st symbol, being a lock, means that the repository is private.

The 2nd symbol depicts part of a commit graph, with one node branching into two. In version control systems, it would mean either a branch or a fork. Since this is the repository list, it means the repository itself is considered a [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) by GitHub.